# How do I align the container at the top with my navigation bar in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

new to bootstrap! I am trying to align the navigation bar and the top title. The yellow area is wider than the navigation bar. I also need help setting the background image to span the whole website. If anyone can give me some suggestions, it would be appreciated!

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!doctype html>


<div class="container bg-warning">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <p class="display-1">Thuan's Website</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand" />
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/30/000000/redo.png" />Thuan
    </a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home
                </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Forums
                </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Games
                </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact
                </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is Your code to put Background image.Please provide that too..!

Comment: I have no idea for the code about the background image, I've been searching for it and couldn't come to a conclusion for the answer!

Comment: Check this for [Background Image](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the title and navbar full width just put it oustside container class

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center  bg-warning">
  <p class="display-1">Thuan's Website</p>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand" />
  <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/30/000000/redo.png" />Thuan
  </a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home
                </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Forums
                </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Games
                </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact
                </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Amal, I want the yellow area to be the same size as my navigation bar.

Comment: u want it inside container itself?